# Font Awesome Code Not Working - FA-USER-SECRET

Tags: font-awesome

So far all all the icons are working on http://702ishome.com/summerlin-villages/arbors/ except for 1 --- the fa-user-secret icon will not work on my site.

Any thoughts on why it doesn't show while all the others do?

THANKS!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You may consider adding a little context (what codes are you talking about, what extra fonts you are using) to your question. Otherwise it is hard for readers to understand and less likely to yield good answers.

Comment: Ah I thought this was for the awesome fonts community so I guess it's for more than that?

fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/ is the site I use for short codes and the user-secret is not working. All the others I have used are perfect --- this one... not showing up on any page I place it.

Comment: If you don't add more specific tags than just `wordpress`, this question targets much more people than are likely to have an answer. But as you can see, @songdogtech has edited your question and added the `font-awesome` tag, which displays this question more prominently for people subscribed to that tag. Good luck with your website!

Answer (score 4):

You are using version 4.2 of Font Awesome, but `fa-user-secret` was added in 4.3.

Source:

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/whats-new/

Comment: Thanks - it's built into my theme so off to find out from the developer how to fix it!!!

Comment: Good luck! (Also, if I answered your question then you should mark it as answered so other people can see!)

Answer (score 0):

fa fa-user-secret (Normal)
far fa-user-secret (Regular)
fas-user-secret (Solid)

try using variations of the fa, far and the fas... I had an issue where the icon failed to reference Icon in the FontAwesome directory.